# Python stripping characters(words) out of a string

Tags: python

I have a string

```
string = "Friday07:48 AM"
```

How do I get rid of "Friday"? I could simply use a replace() function but this string could also be any other day of the week. So it could look like:

```
string = "Sunday07:48 AM"
```

How do I only get "07:48 AM"?

Answer (score 3):

We can utilize the fact that every day of the week in English ends in the substring 'day' to locate that within your string, and then go from three indices farther from where 'day' starts until the end of your string.

```
date_str = "Friday07:48 AM"
new_str = date_str[date_str.index('day')+3:]
new_str # '07:48 AM'
```

As an aside, never name a string 'string' or 'str', because those are special words in Python.

Comment: `string` is a Python module, but `str` is the string type in python and is also a bad variable name

Comment: @PeterGibson Derp, ty. I rely on my IDE too much for that stuff.

Comment: No problem, I only mention it as I've been bitten by that bug before ;)

Answer (score 0):

Well for everything except Saturday and Wednesday you could just grab it by:

day = string[0:6]

but in the all cases IF the time stamp in the front always holds the same index you could:

day = string[:-8]

Try it in the shell

Answer (score 0):

How about using regular expressions?

```
import re
re.search("([a-z]+)(.*)",string,flags=re.I).group(2)
```

Comment: That just seems to give me "Friday". I'm looking for "07:48 AM".

Comment: I gave you the wrong group id.  Try group 2 and you will get the correct result